# How to ignore .tsx files in webpack?

Tags: typescript

I want to ignore the .tsx files in webpack, but I can't get it to ignore the files, can you help me, please?

This is my webpack config:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            configFile: 'tsconfig.webpack.json',
                        },
                    },
                ],
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.tsx$/],
            },
        ],
    },
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
    },
    devtool: false,
};
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to exclude the `TypeScript test files` ?

Comment: `.tsx` never pass the `/\.ts$/` check so I guess it is the behavior inside `ts-loader`, try to exclude `.tsx` from the `tsconfig` file